# Easier way to remove the stem from a strawberry?

Tags: food, substitute-tool, snack-food

I always have trouble pulling off the stem from my strawberries. Is their a better way to take the stem off without leaving part of the stem still on? Maybe some sort of household tool I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using part of its name!

A good straw pressed through the bottom to push the stem out.

[image: 'Straw'berry]

Comment: The only downside of this is, that you'll lose some of that precious, tasty *straw*berry!

Answer (score 3):

Search your favorite kitchen utensils and gadgets site for a [**strawberry huller**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002XOHZWC). If presentation is important, it does a beautify job with exactly what you are looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I like a [bird's-beak parer](http://ab.wsimgs.com/wsimgs/ab/images/dp/wcm/201533/0190/img63c.jpg), but a vegetable peeler will work pretty well for this. Use it point-first to make a circular cut around the stem, which will come right out. I use this technique for a number of other things - removing eyes from potatoes, scooping blemishes out of fruit, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use a pair of metal tweezers.

Just stab into the top of the strawberry, squeeze, and pull. You'll get the stem, base and all, every time.

Make sure to use a pair that is flat on the end, not the kind with a sharp tip. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Note: Make sure to clean the tweezers first. This should go without saying.